# Return document with all array of objects where element exists

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to return one document with an array of objects where `userAnswer` exists. My query below returns only the first object with the array. What am I missing here? It should return two.

Meteor and MongoDB being used.

MongoDB: `document`

```
{
  _id: 1,
  questions: [
    { question: 'test question', userAnswer: 'answer' },
    { question: 'test question two', userAnswer: 'answertwo' },
    { question: 'test question three' }
  ]
};
```

Mongodb: `Query`

```
ConductedExams.findOne(
  {
    userId,
    examId,
    userCompletedExam: null
  },
  { fields: { questions: { $elemMatch: { userAnswer: { $exists: true } } } } }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

"findOne" return only one element.
You should use "find".

Comment: Plus if `fetch` if it is returned from a Meteor method or used elsewhere. Otherwise it returns a Cursor. In a Publication, however, it is important to return the cursor and not the fetched documents.

Comment: Absolutely. Something like: 

CollectionName.find({ stuff: something }).fetch();